# How to take multiple inputs e.g. an array in a single line in terminal window

Tags: java, arrays

I was running a java code to enter and display the array
But in terminal window when i write the first input and press the enter, the input line changes to next.
Instead of this i want to take input in a single line.
When i have to make an 4×4 2-d arrays and while entering the inputs to the array, it takes 16 lines for the input.
I want to take all the inputs to an array in a single line.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may meet your requirements.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] arr = new int[4][4];

    System.out.print("Enter 16 integers separated by a space: ");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] elements = line.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i * 4 + j]);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

After executing the code, type 16 numbers separated by spaces in the terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use input as nextInt();
This will terminate when whitespace occur.

just pass input in one line using space and at the end press enter.

```
public class matrix {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[][] arr = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

[Check Output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0Gs.png)